# Raspberry PI connect to Arduino using XBEE and serve as a Web Server

Tags: arduino, xbee

I would like to know whether if I implemented the internal connection between 2 device (Raspberry Pi to Arduino using XBEE), is it possible in the same time to enable Raspberry PI as Web Server that can be access from Iphone app? For i.e Raspberry Pi serve as Web Server to display Temperature while getting the Temp data from Arduino using XBEE RF Communication

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use a Raspberry Pi this way. One example: [pool thermometer project](http://www.instructables.com/id/Pool-Controller-Using-Raspberry-Pi-Arduino-and-Xbe/).

Btw: you could attach a temperature sensor like DS18B20 directly to the RPi, but this is off-topic.